# Console app in Visual Studio works in Debug but crashes on OleDBConnection in Release?

Tags: visual-studio, oledbconnection

I have a console app that opens an oleDBConnection to access some data from a FoxPro database.

The app works great when I run in Debug.  However, if I try to run the app in Release rather than Debug, I crash on the line conn.Open(); with an error stating that my VFPOLEDB.1 provider is not registered on the local machine.

I'm not sure what it means by that since there seemed to be no problem with the provider when run in Debug mode and all the data was successfully returned from the database.

Any ideas on what may be going on here?

Thanks tons!

Comment: By "run in debug" do you mean "running inside the debugger" or "running the debug build"?

Comment: Just a thought - is your code compiled for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows? In Debug do you run 32-bit and in Release you run 64-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio you have is 32-bit, right? And process started out of VS is 64-bit, guess I right?

Set up the project as x86 and the error could disappear.

Comment: Sure enough.  I've got a 64-bit machine and had the project set to compile to Any CPU.  I changed it to x86 and things run great.